# Rails 3 upgrade : Call javascript function from js.erb with an array as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Upgrading an old Rails application, I want to switch from prototype to Jquery, with unobstrusive javascript.

I have a javascript function js_avancements defined in public/javascripts/application.js (this function will move to another js file when I will switch to assets pipeline mode).

```
function js_avancements (nb_bars, bars_values, bars_names) {
    // test code
    alert(nb_bars);
    for (var i=0; i<nb_bars; i++) {
        alert(bars_names[i] + " : " + bars_values[i].toString());
    }
}
```

My old function in controller (Rails 2 / prototype) is

```
def avancements
  # Here I get values from DB
  # nb_bars = integer
  # bar_values = array of integers
  # bar_names = array of strings

  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html "menu_avancement", :partial => "menu_avancement"
    page.replace_html "show_avancement", :partial => "show_avancement_clean"
    page.call 'js_avancements', nb_bars, bar_values, bar_names
  end
end
```

The new version (Rails 3 / JQuery)
In controller :

```
def avancements
  # Here I get values from DB
  # @nb_bars = integer
  # @bar_values = array of integers
  # @bar_names = array of strings
  # Values for test
  @nb_bars = 4
  @bars_values = [10,17,12,8]
  @bars_names = ['Aaa', 'Bbb', 'Ccc', 'Ddd']

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render "update_avancements" }
  end
end
```

My view (update_avancements.js.erb)

```
$('#menu_avancement').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'menu_avancement')) %>');
$('#show_avancement').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'show_avancement_clean')) %>');
$(document).ready(function() {
  js_avancements(<%=@nb_bars%>, <%=@bars_values%>, <%=@bars_names%>);
});
```

I can't get values from arrays (bar_values & bar_names) in my javascript function.
If I call my javascript function with integer or string parameters only, all is working but with array nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

PS : sorry for my English, you are welcome to correct it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument is what's most probably giving you an issue.  I'm betting the js response looks something like

```
js_avancements(4, [10,17,12,8], [&quotAaa&quot, &quotBbb&quot, &quotCcc&quot, &quotDdd&quot])
```

Use `to_json` or `to_s` with `html_safe` to fix this.

```
js_avancements(<%= @nb_bars.to_s.html_safe %>, <%= @bars_values.to_s.html_safe %>, <%= @bars_names.to_s.html_safe %>);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working ! I tried to_s and to_json but without .html_safe it was not working. Can you explain me why it was working in my old Rails 2 version and no more in this one?

Comment: Here's an article created by Yehuda Katz http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/